# Getting all l10n values stored in localized bundle

Tags: localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, l10n.js

I'm building a FF extension, and I'm processing some xhtml for myself in order to supporn subforms loading, so I have to identify the elements with l10n attributes defined and add them the string value. Because the l10n can't be shared from main code to content scripts (because isn't a simple JSON object), I managed the situation by getting the loaded keys values and defining an "localized array bundle", like this:

```
lStrings = ["step_title", ........ ];
for (var i = 0; i < lStrings.length; i++) {
    bundle[lStrings[i]] = this.locale(lStrings[i]);
}
```

The thing is, I have to write here every entry in the .properties files... SO, do you know how to access this key values? I already tryed with .toString .toLocalString and inspecting the object, but can't find the way the object to be capable of returning all the key collection.

Do you have a better idea for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var yourStringBundle = Services.strings.createBundle('chrome://blah@jetpack/content/bootstrap.properties?' + Math.random()); /* Randomize URI to work around bug 719376 */

var props = yourStringBundle.getSimpleEnumeration();
// MDN says getSimpleEnumeration returns nsIPropertyElement // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIStringBundle#getSimpleEnumeration%28%29

while (props.hasMoreElements()) {
  var prop = props.getNext();
  // doing console.log(prop) says its an XPCWrappedObject but we see QueryInterface (QI), so let's try QI'ing to nsiPropertyElement

  var propEl = prop.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIPropertyElement);
  // doing console.log(propEl) shows the object has some fields that interest us

  var key = propEl.key;
  var str = propEl.value;

  console.info(key, str); // there you go
}
```

See comments for learning. Nice quesiton. I learned more about QI from replying.

Comment: Thanks Noitidart! You helped me a lot by understanding the desktop environment! I just knew FF for Android

Comment: @gal007 you need to return the favor and show me the Android  env! :)

Comment: @Noitidatr no problem! I will watch your questions and hope I can help you!

Comment: Sorry for the so long delay. I just tested the solution you provided, but the thing is I can't create a bundle. It already exist (so I shouldn't do var yourStringBundle =...). Even trying that (with the updated SDK code: var { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome'); var Service = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/stringbundle;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStringBundleService);) 
I can't do it, because the file is never found. 

The only object I can debug is the l10n object, but it just expose the get message... (require("sdk/l10n"))

Comment: I localize all my addons, I use createStringBundle regularly. If you are getting an error, it means your path to the file is wrong. The way this works is it loads a file containing localizations. Check out this example - https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/properties - I think localization in the SDK is different, you arent doing .properties huh?

Comment: Well, I have the .property files. The thing is the APIs are not exactly the same. E.g. I do not have a Services.strings object. I have to call it through Service.createBundle. And even that way, I'm getting:

Comment: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIStringBundle.getSimpleEnumeration]

Comment: And some: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul : Unable to run script because scripts are blocked internally.

Comment: Solved, it's exactly as your example, but using resource instead of chrome. That worked from SDK :)

Comment: Fantastic sharing of your progress and comments Im sure it will come of help to someone